# revtex4-2.cls error with an older TeX distribution

Tags: errors, revtex

I am using the `revtex4-2` class file for the first time to compile my `.tex` file. However, I am getting the following compilation error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \AddToHook 
                      {begindocument/before}{\document@inithook }
l.211   }
```

Here is a minimal working example.

```
\documentclass[aps,prl]{revtex4-2}
\begin{document}
This is APS RevTex 4.2 document class.
\end{document}
```

I have previously used `revtex4-0` as well as `revtex4-1` without any issue. I have recently installed `revtex4.2e` in my system. However, I am unable to figure out the problem I am facing with this latest RevTeX class.

Below is the log file.

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3 (TeX Live 2013/Debian) (format=xelatex 2019.1.4)  19 DEC 2020 19:38
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**main
(./main.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9h> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(./revtex4-2.cls
Document Class: revtex4-2 2020/10/03 4.2e (https://journals.aps.org/revtex/ for
 documentation)
 Copyright (c) 2019 American Physical Society.
 mailto:revtex@aps.org
 Licensed under the LPPL:
http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/base/lppl.txt
 Arthur Ogawa <arthur_ogawa at sbcglobal dot net>
 Based on work by David Carlisle <david at dcarlisle.demon.co.uk>
 Version (4.2d,4.2e): Modified by Mark Doyle and Phelype Oleinik
 .
ltxutil[2020/10/03 4.2e utilities package (portions licensed from W. E. Baxter 
web at superscript.com)]
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \AddToHook 
                      {begindocument/before}{\document@inithook }
l.211   }
         
? x
 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 78 strings out of 493918
 768 string characters out of 6150564
 52172 words of memory out of 5000000
 3498 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1144 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 14i,0n,10p,147b,10s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
No pages of output.
```

Comment: Please add a minimal working example to your question.

Comment: Sounds as if you have an old latex.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Which TeX distribution is installed on your system, and when did you update it most recently?

Comment: The error is weird indeed, because usages of `\AddToHook` in `revtex4-2` are guarded by conditionals that check if LaTeX is new enough... There is something really strange in your document.  Your example compiles fine for me both in a recent and in an old system.  Can you please show the `.log` file?

Comment: Also, it looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](//tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Comment: Hm... You're using a really old system (TeXLive 2013) with a new RevTeX, and that indeed breaks.  Give me a minute

Answer (score 7):

This happens because the line in RevTeX that checks your version of LaTeX:

```latex
\rvtx@ifformat@geq{2020-10-01}%
  {<code for new LaTeX>}
  {<code for old LaTeX>}
```

uses the date in the format `yyyy-mm-dd`, but this date format was only added to LaTeX in 2017, but your version is from 2013, and it only supports dates in the format `yyyy/mm/dd`, so the test above fails and it tries to execute the `<code for new LaTeX>` instead.

While RevTeX isn't updated again to use the old date format, use this patch to teach your version of LaTeX the new date format (and *please* update your TeX system!).  The patch must be added *before* the `\documentclass` line:

```latex
% Patch to make old LaTeX understand dates in yyyy-mm-dd format
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{@parse@version@dash}{%
\def\@parse@version#1{\@parse@version@0#1}
\def\@parse@version@#1/#2/#3#4#5\@nil{%
\@parse@version@dash#1-#2-#3#4\@nil}
\def\@parse@version@dash#1-#2-#3#4#5\@nil{%
  \if\relax#2\relax\else#1\fi#2#3#4 }
}{}
\makeatother

% document
\documentclass[aps,prl]{revtex4-2}
\begin{document}
This is APS RevTex 4.2 document class.
\end{document}
```